# width:auto not working right for absolutely positioned div when scroll bar is present

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some content that's absolutely positioned and has an explicit height. When the content goes outside the height, a scroll bar appears, but it doesn't respect my width:auto - the scroll bars cover up the content.

Example:

```
<style>    
    #main {
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }

</style>

<div id='main'>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>testiiiiiiiing</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
</div>
```

What's going on here? Is this browser bug? How can I make it correctly respect my automatic width?

Comment: You're re-using ID's...you can't do that. Probably not related though...but then again?

Comment: Fixed, and not related

Comment: What’s the browser in question?

Comment: Chrome and firefox both seem to operate this way

Answer (score 3):

You can use `overflow-y: scroll;`

```
<style>

 #main {
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: absolute;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
 #a {}

</style>
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVKMNB)

Comment: I'm flabbergasted that the scrollbar that appears with 'auto' doesn't act the same as one that appears with 'scroll'. CSS truly is the stupidest technology. Problem is, I don't want scroll bars to appear if my content can fit in the specified height. I really *want* what overflow:auto is supposed to do. Any other ideas?

Comment: @BT the issue isn't that CSS isn't the stupiest technology, but when browser people implemented the scrollbar, there's absolutely no spec whether they should take that into account or not. the best advice i can give is to give your divs some extra padding to the right

Comment: And no one thought "hey, someone might want both options"? Also, i'm not complaining about scroll bars being inside vs outside. I'm complaining about the inconsistent behavior between `overflow:auto` scrollbars and `overflow:scroll` scrollbars. There are  many MANY things stupid about css. This is just one example.

Comment: Upvoting this since it at least gives me an option I can robustly use with javascript manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Two possiblties occur to me although it's unlikely you will find many words being 100px wide.

First, just add some `padding-right` to make space for the scrollbar.

```css
    .main {
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: absolute;
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturametconsectetur.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Secondly, force all words to break if they reach that far edge using `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
.main {
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: absolute;
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
    .main.breaking {
      padding-right: none;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main breaking">
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Loremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturametconsectet</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
  <div class="a">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a consistent with browsers have for scroll bars? If not, `padding-right` isn't a very robust workaround. Break-word technically works (the words are no longer obscured, but its not the behavior I want unfortunately.